# What could be causing XCode to not display warnings in issue navigator?

Tags: xcode

XCode 13.2.1 suddenly stopped displaying warnings in the issue navigator for (Obj-C) project builds and analyze. It only displays: "No Buildtime Issues". Which is not correct: the Report navigator shows the warnings OK. When I deliberately make a source file uncompilable by inserting some bad syntax, the compile errors get displayed OK in the issue navigator. The issue navigator is unfiltered, and "show only errors" is off. I have restarted XCode, cleaned build folders and restarted the Mac, all to no avail. Any idea what's causing this?